# replacing mutated vowel form a string

Tags: java, replace

I'm looking for a nice way of replacing all mutated vowel within a string by their "unmutated" vowel(combinations).

Basically it is like:

```
"ä" -> "ae"  
"ö" -> "oe"  
"ß" -> "sz"  
"Š" -> "S"  
"ć" -> "c"
```

and so on ...

I know I could create a map for this and do it maybe with a loop to replacing all occurrences but that looks awful.
Further I have to create a complete mapping likst form "mutated" to "unmutated".

Is there a more elegant way in Java to do so?

Note: I have to support Java 1.8

Comment: Setting up a map looks like a clean, readable and xtensible solution to me...

Comment: Do you know the language of these strings? Because, for example, in German ö → oe is correct, but in Dutch the best substitution is probably just ö → o. And ß → sz is questionable even in German.

Comment: These "mutation rules" are language and culture specific. The ones in this question specifically look like they might be for German. You are not going to find something that fits your needs exactly in the standard library. Are you looking for recommendations for an external library?

Comment: @Thomas:It is not only german, other special mutated vowels may appear as well. Even I think it would be better to simply map them to the one letter replacement (ä ->a)

Comment: @Joni:It is not only german, other special mutated vowels may appear as well. Even I think it would be better to simply map them to the one letter replacement (ä ->a) if there is one library yes I'm looking for it.

Comment: @Turing85:Not to me - is would be very tedious and never "complete"

Comment: Consonants should not be changed? Ñ should remain as it is, same for Ğ etc? What about Greek, what transformation do you expect for ά?  It would help if you explained what you're trying to accomplish here